# using .ajax to submit and display data but css doesn't take effect until page is literally refreshed

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am using jquery's .ajax function to send data to a database table and display the data on the page without refreshing the page.

In the query where I am displaying the content from the db table, each entry is wrapped in a div class named *.wrap*

The class has a bottom margin of 30 pixels. When I use my form, and the newly added data is displayed the css doesn't show up. The margin is non-existent, but wheni refresh the page manually the css takes affect. What could be the problem? Below is my code

```
$(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {

        var data = $(this).serialize();

        // Stop the form actually posting
        e.preventDefault();

        // Send the request
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submit.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                var error = '';

                if (!$.trim($("#cat").val())) {
                    error = "<p>the cat field is empty</p>";
                }

                if (!$.trim($("#box").val())) {
                    error += "<p>the box field is empty</p>";
                }

                if (error) {
                  $(".fb-error").html(error);
                  $(".fb-error").css( "display", "block" );
                  xhr.abort();
                }                       

                },
            success: function(html){
                 $(".fb-error").css( "display", "none" );
                $('textarea#box').val('');
                $("#box-wrap").prepend(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT:

The problem is that when i submit my form and the content appears for the first time my .wrap class is not present around the new content. but when I refresh the page the .wrap class is present around the newly added content.

So the problem is a lack of the .wrap class immediately after the new content appears but I don't know why or how to fix it. The .wrap class is around each piece of data except the new piece.

Each row is inside it's own class. Like

```
<div class="wrap">row 3</div>
<div class="wrap">row 2</div>
<div class="wrap">row 1</div>
```

This is what it looks like when I add a new entry to the db when sending my form via ajax.

```
row 4
<div class="wrap">row 3</div>
<div class="wrap">row 2</div>
<div class="wrap">row 1</div>
```

After I refresh it looks like

```
<div class="wrap">row 4</div>
<div class="wrap">row 3</div>
<div class="wrap">row 2</div>
<div class="wrap">row 1</div>
```

The way I am displaying my results on my server side

```
foreach ($query as $row) {
        echo '<div class="wrap">' . $row["box"] . '</div>';
    }
```

Here is my submit.php. I've wiped everything out for troubleshooting.. This is exactly what i am currently working with.

```
include 'connect.php';

$string = strip_tags($_POST["box"]);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO boxes (box) VALUES (:box)");

$stmt->execute(array(
":box" => $string
));
```

Comment: After your AJAX call the output HTML is probably not what you're expecting. When you refresh the HTML is generated differently. Use your browser's inspector to find out which CSS rules are being applied (and which aren't).

Comment: This could be a needle in a haystack type of problem.  I'd recommend getting both versions of the page open and inspecting the elements with the developer tools to figure out what the difference is.  Once you know what it is then you can figure out how to fix it.

Comment: I know what the difference is. After I submit my form and the content appears the .wrap class isn't present around the newly added content. But when I refresh the .wrap class is present.

Comment: @gregor Is the `.wrap` class on the element(s) it should be after the AJAX? If not, the server-side code that returns the HTML needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Anthony, I don't know what you mean. I have a php loop that displays a row from a table in my my db. Each row entry that is displayed is displayed inside of a class named .wrap. When I submit my form, and the data sent to the newly added row appears it is not inside of a .wrap class. But when I refresh the page it is inside a .wrap class.

Comment: @gregor What do you mean "inside of a class named .wrap"? CSS classes are applied to elements; which element has/should have the `wrap` class? Is it each individual row or is it the element that you're putting the new HTML inside of (the one that always exists on the page)?

Comment: @gregor Under `success:` add `console.log(html)` and view your browser's Dev Tools console to make sure that the HTML being returned actually has the `div.wrap` around it.

Comment: @Anthony, I added to my OP.
shshaw, I all ready know it does not have it around it. I used firebug and saw the difference before and after.

Comment: @gregor The jQuery is irrelevant here. You need to modify the server-side code to return `<div class="wrap">row 4</div>` rather than just `row 4`.

Comment: you should really post up the code for `submit.php`

Comment: @Anthony, my server side does have the div wrapped in it. (I added to my OP to show you.) The server side knows to add the class, and it does. But only after i manually refresh the page. David, my submit.php isn't causing any conflict. This is the jquery. My server side is fine. It knows to add the class and it does. Only after I manually refresh.

Comment: @gregor The jQuery is doing everything you've coded it to; an AJAX request is sent, that reaches the server, the server sends a response, and then that response is prepended to an element. Any issues are caused by the response from the server; what does that actually look like?

Comment: @Anthony, that doesn't make sense. The server side is handling everything correctly. Is does add the class around each row. Just like it is told to. it is just weird because immediately after i send my form via ajax the new content shows up without the div,but when I refresh manually the class is around the data.There is nothing I could possibly change in the server side that would make a difference. If I remove the js, submit my form, and go back to the page everything is rendered just like it is supposed to. The problem has to be coming from the prepend.

Comment: My submit.php is literally down to nothing but $_POST and a query to insert the content into the db. There are no extra frills, and you can see how my foreach is set up in the OP. I know this has to be the prepend or something else in the js. If this were a server side issue everything wouldn't be displayed correctly after I manually refresh.

Comment: @gregor right before your `prepend` in your `success` function, put an alert: `alert(html)` or log it to your Firebug console `console.log(html)`. What does that show? Do you see the full HTML entity with it's class or just the text `row 4`?

Comment: @gregor Just post the full response from the AJAX call already. If the issue is caused by the `prepend` it's because there's an issue with what you're passing it, and that comes from your server.

Comment: I found the problem. The ajax isn't actually sending any data. It isn't collecting anything from the data variable. The submit.php was doing everything. I have an echo in my submit.php that echos the new data. Whenever the jquery would prepend it was showing me the echoed out msg, but I thought I was seeing the newly added db data via my foreach. Which is why I had to manually refresh to see the new data with the class around it because the php was doing it all. But now I've got to figure out why my js isn't sending anything. Is there something wrong with my data variable in my js?

Comment: do `console.log(data);` the line after you serialize it and check.  Without seeing what you are sending and without seeing the php that deals with it it's impossible to know.

Comment: @gregor try moving your `e.preventDefault();` down below the AJAX call

Comment: I'm sending an input field named 'box' and as far as my php I'm doing $_POST['box'] just to keep things simple until I figure out my problem. When i logged the ajax to see what was being sent it showed me a br so I looked at my php and realized I had left my echo in my php so I took it out. Then I sent the form and logged the ajax. It displayed absolutely nothing. That is when i realized i had been looking at that echo the entire time and nothing was being sent via ajax but entirely php. Which explained the having to refresh.

Comment: @FastTrack, no go. Absolutely nothing is being sent via ajax. It has to be with my data variable most likely. The php is submitting everything fine.

Comment: @gregor Yes, that's all fine.  Now do `console.log(data);` the line after you serialize the data and check what you are sending. **Without seeing what you are sending and without seeing the php that deals with it it's impossible to know what is wrong.**

Comment: @archer, I added my submit.php to the OP i don't think it will really provide any insight. The AJAX is literally sending nothing. The php is sending everything correctly. I'm assuming it has to do with the data variable and my serialize.

Comment: @gregor The php you have shown is not returning anything.  The data is **correctly** being passed by the ajax call and inserted into the database or a refresh would not show the new data.  It is the response from your submit page that is incorrect.

Comment: Archer, you're wrong. the reason the refresh shows the new data is because the php sent the data to the database. If the ajax were sending the data I would not need to refresh. I can do away with the ajax all together and everything is sent right along to the database. The reason refreshing reveals new data is because the php sent it and not the ajax.. Not trying to be an ass, but i know that much is correct. Whenever i check to see what the ajax is sending I am returned with nothing, but when I check the php i see everything.

Comment: @gregor No, you are wrong.  The php that inserts the data into the database is being executed *by* the ajax call.  It is not possible for that data to be inserted into the database any other way since you have disabled the default action of the form with `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Archer the ajax is still using submit.php. The ajax still triggers submit.php. The submit.php then gathers the data. Do you understand now?

Comment: That's why the data is being inserted into the database.  Ajax sends the data to submit.php which inserts it into the database.  That php file then responds to the ajax call with **nothing**, which is what you get in the success function.  Your submit.php **needs** to return something for the success function to use.  Do you understand now?

Comment: @Archer, the form data is being collected by my $_POST in the submit.php. The data variable in my js isn't sending anything. That is why I have to refresh. because the php did everything. All ajax is doing correctly is using the submit.php

Comment: Are you saying that I need to write extra php for the ajax to work?

Comment: Sorry, but you have 0 comprehension of what you're talking about and it's like trying to explain something to a brick wall.  If you won't listen then I can't help you.

Comment: I've suggested closing this question because `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.`

Comment: You're the brick wall. I do understand. i just think you don't understand what I'm trying to tell you. You're going round and round. You can insult me all day but you haven't offer any solution or understanding to the problem thatI'm explaining. What do i need to do differently? I mean the php is sendingthe data the ajax is sending nothing. What is missing? Ajax is not sendiny ANY data.. Thesubmit.php is collecting it.

Comment: I'mthe one who figured out the issue.. So i have demonstrated an understanding. Now i just need to find out why the ajax isn't sending anything.. You told me to listen, but you haven't said anything new. You're stuck on the SAME thing. The ajax triggers submit.php the submi.php uses $_POST to collect the data and send it. That is why I must refresh. There is nothing wrong with the php. It has to be the ajax. Why else would the ajax return absolutely nothing?

Comment: I'll try once more.  PHP isn't *magically* getting the data and inserting it into the database.  The ajax call is passing the data, as a `POST`, to submit.php.  That php file then does what it needs to do and the output (in this case an empty page) is sent back to the ajax success function in the form of the parameter (in your case, `html`).  So, when you have the line `$("#box-wrap").prepend(html);` it is prepending the selected element with *nothing*, which is what your perfectly working php is returning.  If you don't believe me just put `echo "I'm a coding noob";` at the end of submit.php

Comment: By using `strip_tags` in your Submit.php, the `<div class="wrap">` is getting removed before being dropped in the database, therefore the Submit.php is not returning the `<div class="wrap">` portion if it is returning `$string` to the AJAX call.

Comment: @shshaw, I'm not submitting the html through the form. The html is displayed on its own via the server side code. It is done after everything is submitted. Poor Angry brick wall Archer.. If you were paying attention you'd have saw I mentioned that above, but whatever, guy. I do like how you tried to actually explain something for the first time and act like you had been saying it all along though. Don't worry. I fixed it last night. I was right and you were wrong. Try not to be so angry, guy. Life can be such a happier existence.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted @gregor.  Hopefully your lesson has been learnt that when you're new to something and experts (plural) try to help you, don't tell them they're wrong unless you're actually right ;)

Comment: But I was right and you were wrong. And you are the only person i told was wrong. I didn't tell anyone but you, but we all know that and that you are saying I did because your ego got hurt. It's fixed and that is all that matters, @ angry angry archer.. Thanks though.

Comment: @gregor I'm just glad you got it sorted - that's all.  Now you know that you were wrong, just like you were in your other questions in your question history, which is quite a funny read, by the way.  "Why do my 2 if statements not run?" when one of them is "else if".  LOL.  Like I said, I'm glad you got the help you needed and finally solved your little issue by putting the required response at the end of the PHP file, as suggested.  Well done :)

Comment: Oh, and you can have the last word in this, as I *know* you need it.  I'll not post here again.  Have fun learning to code :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this...

```
$("#box-wrap").prepend(html);
```

...to this...

```
$("#box-wrap").prepend('<div class="wrap">' + html + '</div>');
```

And it should work just fine (assuming your AJAX always only comes back with one row to add - if not, you'd need to make that same change on the server side, or else do some more complex parsing of the results).

Comment: That defeats my whole purpose and is an extra step that shouldn't need to be done.

Comment: It does need to be done.  AJAX/JQuery has no way of knowing what you want to do with the data it's returning, unless you tell it.  Your AJAX call appears to simply be returning the value "row 4" with no surrounding HTML tags... so, that's literally what it prepends to the "#box-wrap" element.  The HTML tags you want to surround that value need to either be added by the page the AJAX call is calling or else by the code that prepends the value.